# Only add data to ajax call if it isnt a null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this div

```
<div class='additional_comments'>
    <input type="text" id='additional_comments_box', maxlength="200"/>
</div>
```

Which will only sometimes appear on the page if jinja renders it with an if statement.

This is the javascript i have to send an ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $("#send");

    $(button).click(function() {
        var vals = [];
        $("#answers :input").each(function(index) {
            vals.push($(this).val());
        });
        vals = JSON.stringify(vals);
        console.log(vals);
        var comment = $('#additional_comments_box').val();

        var url = window.location.pathname;
        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'vals': vals,
            'comment': comment,
            },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            location.href = data.url;//<--Redirect on success
        }
        });
     });

    });
```

As you can see i get the comments div, and I want to add it to `data` in my ajax request, however if it doesnt exist, how do I stop it being added.

Thanks

Comment: How many inputs you have with `additional_comments_box` id?

Comment: @Eddie just 1 input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.length` property to check elements exists based on it populate the object.

```
//Define object
var data = {}; 

//Populate vals
data.vals = $("#answers :input").each(function (index) {
    return $(this).val();
});

//Check element exists
var cbox = $('#additional_comments_box');
if (cbox.length){ 
    //Define comment
    data.comment = cbox.val();
}

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```